# If $np + c \sqrt{npq}$ is an integer, does there exits infinitely many $n_1<n_2<n_3\dots$ such that $n_ip + c \sqrt{n_ipq}$ is an integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Consider the following situtation: given $p \in (0,1)$, $q:=1- p$ and and some $k<n \in \mathbb N$ we define
$$
c := \frac{k - np}{\sqrt{npq}}. 
$$

> I would like to motivate that there exists an infinite sequence $n <
>  n_1 < n_2 < \dots$ such that  $$ c = \frac{k_i - n_i p}{\sqrt{n_i
> > pq}}. $$ for some interger $k_i$, or equivalently, such that $$ n_i p
> > + c \sqrt{n_i pq} $$ is an integer.

I got stuch on this, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about $n_i=i^2\times n$?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me that this will be the case if e.g. $p$ is transcendental. This obviously looks like a question about binomial distributions; it might help to ask the 'baseline' probability question rather than (or in addition to) the question about integrality of this expression.

Answer (score 1):

Three cases:

- $np\in\Bbb N$: If $np+\sqrt{npq}$ is an integer, $n m^2 p+\sqrt{n m^2 pq}=m(nmp+\sqrt{npq})$ is also an integer provided $m\in\Bbb N$. Therefore, choosing $n_i=(i+1)^2\times n$ results in $n<n_1<n_2<\dots$ and, for all $i$, $n_ip+\sqrt{n_ipq}\in\Bbb Z$.
- $np\in\Bbb Q$: Let $p=\frac{a}{b}$.

\begin{aligned}
np+\sqrt{npq}&=n\frac{a}{b}+\sqrt{n\frac{a}{b}\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)}\\
&=\frac{n}{b}\left[ a+\sqrt{n\left(b-a^2\right)}\right]
\end{aligned}

and, therefore, $\left[ a+\sqrt{n\left(b-a^2\right)}\right]$ is a multiple of $b$. Choosing $m$ so that $m-1$ is a multiple of $b$ makes $\left[ am+\sqrt{n\left(b-a^2\right)}\right]$ also divisible by $b$.

- If $p\in\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$. I'm not very clear as to what needs to happen for $np+\sqrt{npq}\in \Bbb N$. My guess is that this cannot happen except for vey specific $p$ and $n$, but I couldn't figure out an example.

Comment: Why? $np+\sqrt{npq}$ being an integer doesn't ensure that $nmp+\sqrt{npq}$ is if, e.g., $np\not\in\mathbb{Z}$... (note that $p,q$ here are probabilities, not prime numbers)

Comment: @Steven Yes, I tried a similar approach myself, but wasn't able to motivate why $nmp + \sqrt{npq}$ should be an integer an integer.

Comment: I think you're missing the factor of $c$ in the original post, too; you can choose arbitrary $p$ and $n$ and then find $c$ from them.